# Can I stop edges in graphs from drawing on top of the vertices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the following

```
testadj = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[0.15], {50, 50}];
AdjacencyGraph[testadj, VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]

The nodes are almost completely hidden in the mess of edges. They can be made easier to see by making the edges fade into the background a little.

```
AdjacencyGraph[testadj, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.4], Gray], 
 VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]

But we still have the problem that the lines draw over the top of the nodes. Is there a way to force the nodes to draw on top of the lines?

Comment: I have a feeling this has been asked before, or at least came up in a question.  I can't find it unfortunately.

Comment: Do you need to keep the graph functionality or would it be enough to create a `Graphics` (not `Graph`) object that has the vertices on top?

Comment: @Szabolcs This one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8205128/353410

Comment: @belisarius - it's a different problem.

Comment: @Verbeia Look at Mr's answer :)

Comment: @belisarius yeah, +1 for the smilies and the solution. I probably should have specified that we have a `HighlightGraph` in there. My colleague is actually doing this and he is a new Mathematica user, so anything that allows us to keep it as a `Graph` rather than a `GraphPlot`, at least up to final rendering, is preferable in our specific application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** In recent versions, vertices render on top. The rendering order can be controlled as follows:

```
testadj = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[0.15], {50, 50}];
AdjacencyGraph[testadj, VertexSize -> Large, 
   GraphLayout -> {"RenderingOrder" -> #}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {"EdgeFirst", "VertexFirst"}
```

[image]

---

This is a nasty hack.  It might be the quickest workaround until you find a solution.

```
testadj = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[0.15], {50, 50}];
gr = AdjacencyGraph[testadj, VertexSize -> Large]

Show[gr, SetProperty[gr, EdgeShapeFunction -> ({} &)]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The end result is a `Graphics` object, not a `Graph`.  I am using `{}` as a "neutral graphics object", something that is accepted inside `Graphics`, but does not render.

Unfortunately the analogous `SetProperty[gr, VertexShapeFunction -> ({} &)]` does not seem to work, and I don't understand why.  It may have to do something with the fact that the system analyses the vertex shape to make the edges join up nicely to them.  If you need to make them disappear, you can use `SetProperty[gr, VertexShape -> None]`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my implementation by modifying the Box structures.

```
Clear[vertexFirstShow]
vertexFirstShow[graph_] :=
    Module[{graphdata, vShow},
           graphdata = ToBoxes[graph];
           vShow = 
                  Cases[graphdata, GraphicsGroupBox[{v_, e_}] :> v, \[Infinity]][[1]]
                       /. {
                           TagBox[DiskBox[pos_, r_], "DynamicName", BoxID -> id_]
                                :> DiskBox[DynamicLocation[id], r],
                           TagBox[StyleBox[DiskBox[pos_, r_], opts__], "DynamicName", BoxID -> id_]
                                :> StyleBox[DiskBox[DynamicLocation[id], r], opts]
                          };
           With[{v2 = vShow},
                ToExpression[
                      graphdata /. GraphicsGroupBox[{v_, e_}] :> GraphicsGroupBox[{v, e, v2}]]
          ]]

testadj = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[0.15], {50, 50}];

graph = AdjacencyGraph[testadj, VertexSize -> Large, GraphHighlight -> {1, 2, 3}]

vertexFirstShow[graph]
```

[image]

It retains a `Graph` object, and I'm sure the code can be improved to fit more complicated cases.

Comment: Really nice solution, thanks! I accepted @Szabolcs' because it was sufficient for our purposes.

Comment: @Verbeia His answer is great. It never comes to my mind to use `EdgeShapeFunction` like that. :)

Answer (score 4):

`GraphPlot` does alright.  Perhaps `Inset` is the key.

```
testadj = RandomInteger[BernoulliDistribution[0.15], {50, 50}];

(* gr = graphic *)

GraphPlot[testadj, VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[gr, #1] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I´d go for the [Evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Evolution_movie.jpg) smiley ;-)

Comment: Having our Q&A in two different sites makes us repeat ourselves :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885910/mathematica-graphplot-with-images/8205128#8205128

Comment: This is a similar solution but the problem is actually different.

Answer (score 3):

You can always extract full info from `Graph` and then use graphics primitives. It is more elaborate but it gives full control.

```
testadj = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[0.15], {50, 50}];
g = AdjacencyGraph[testadj, VertexSize -> 0];
Show[g, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates][[2]]]}]]
```

[image]