# Find size of vertex image relative to the graph coordinate system

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I am trying to define a graph using my own `VertexShapeFunction` with an `ActionMenu` button being the vertex and a custom `EdgeShapeFunction` defining the edges as arrows.

My problem is that I am unable to get the arrows to finish exactly at the border of the `ActionMenu` as it is when I leave `EdgeShapeFunction` to `Automatic`. The coordinates and relative size of the `ActionMenu` button depends on the number of vertices and their layout, so I cannot compute once the coordinates and hardcode them in my definition of the `EdgeShapeFunction`.

I was wondering if there is a function or a way to get the relative size to the graph coordinate system of the `ActionMenu` button or some dimensions.

Here is an image of what I am trying to get: as seen from the image, the arrows are ending just before they reach the vertex:

[image: picture]

Here is part of the code:

```
ef[el_, __] := {Blue, 
  Which[First[el][[1]] < Last[el][[1]], 
   Arrow[{First[el], First[el] + {Last[el][[1]] - 0.5, 0}, 
     Last[el] - {0.5, 0}, Last[el] - {0.400, 0}}],

   First[el][[1]] >= Last[el][[1]], 
   Arrow[{First[el], First[el] + {1.5, 0}, First[el] + {1.5, -0.5}, 
     Last[el] + {-1.5, -0.5 + First[el][[2]] - Last[el][[2]]}, 
     Last[el] - {1.5, 0}, Last[el] - {0.400, 0}}]]}

g = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, 
   VertexShapeFunction -> (Inset[
       ActionMenu[
        icon, {"Print" :> Print[#2]}], #] &), 
   EdgeShapeFunction -> ef, 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Italic, 20]];
```

Comment: It looks like all the edges are drawn before the vertices, so it's going to be difficult to draw them finishing in the right place. I've tried playing with the Inset options and the arguments passed to the vertex shape function, but got nowhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the related question:
[Can I stop edges in graphs from drawing on top of the vertices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8737/can-i-stop-edges-in-graphs-from-drawing-on-top-of-the-vertices/8743#8743)

In your example, you could manually set DynamicName using vertex index.

If we assume vertex names and vertex indices of the given graph are the same, you could modify your function like the below:

```
ef[el_, DirectedEdge[a_, b_]] := {Blue, 
    Which[First[el][[1]] < Last[el][[1]], 
       Arrow[{First[el], First[el] + {Last[el][[1]] - 0.5, 0}, 
         Last[el] - {0.5, 0}, 
         DynamicLocation["VertexID$" <> ToString[b], Automatic, Center]}],
         First[el][[1]] >= Last[el][[1]], 
       Arrow[{First[el], First[el] + {1.5, 0}, First[el] + {1.5, -0.5}, 
         Last[el] + {-1.5, -0.5 + First[el][[2]] - Last[el][[2]]}, 
         Last[el] - {1.5, 0}, 
         DynamicLocation["VertexID$" <> ToString[b], Automatic, 
         Center]}]]}

g = Graph[{1,2,3}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, 
    VertexShapeFunction -> (Inset[
    ActionMenu[icon, {"Print" :> Print[#2]}], #] &), 
    EdgeShapeFunction -> ef, VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Italic, 20]]
```

[image]

note: this works on v9.0.1, but cannot guarantee it will work in the future version of Mathematica (since boxform could be changed)

Comment: Is there anywhere I can read more about DynamicLocation, since I would like to make the length of how much the edge goes in/out of the ActionMenu before changing direction proportional to the size of the button.